# how to include self write function in Django

Tags: django

I want to this code `from feed.function.string import plaintext`

to include the safe_html function is `feed/function/string.py` file, but fail all the time.

an `ImportError` show up:

```
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named function.string
Exception Location: E:\MyProject\auto-system\feed\views.py in <module>, line 3
```

Comment: Can you paste your project layout?

Comment: I want to upload the file structure of my project, but I just sign up, so I don't the the permision to upload a image now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place a `__init__.py`, which could be just an empty file, in the folder `feed` and the folder `function` so that python will know that the directories contain packages.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: thanks, Churix. after adding the __init__.py file, everything work fine.

Comment: You are welcome. You may mark the answer as 'accepted' if it's good. You (and I) will earn reputation for that. :)